# Sorting and printing largest value and associated row name in R table

Tags: r, database

```
              WIDTH LENGTH  DEPTH
  Beam            3     8     34
  Piller          4     2     45
  Frame           7     1     12
```

I have a data table in the above format.  I'm trying to output the row item with the largest value in the DEPTH, as well as the value itself.  So in this case, I'm trying to output:

```
Piller: 45
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below

```
sprintf("%s : %s", row.names(df)[which.max(df$DEPTH)],max(df$DEPTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to exactly output what you asked in base R:

```
subdf <- df[df$DEPTH == max(df$DEPTH),]
> cat(rownames(subdf),": ",subdf[,"DEPTH"])
Piller :  45
```

Here `df[df$DEPTH == max(df$DEPTH),]` gives you the subset where `DEPTH` is max.

But I would encourage you to use the rownames in a column if they are actually data. For example, `data.table` encourage you to keep the rownames as a column, which make its use easier:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df,keep.rownames = T)

dt[DEPTH == max(DEPTH),.(rn,DEPTH)]

       rn DEPTH
1: Piller    45
```

The same with `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

as_tibble(df,rownames = "rn") %>%
  filter(DEPTH == max(DEPTH)) %>%
  select(rn,DEPTH)
```

---

data :

```
df <- read.table(text = "              WIDTH LENGTH  DEPTH
  Beam            3     8     34
           Piller          4     2     45
           Frame           7     1     12",header = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth breakdown.  I'm unfortunately confined to using only base R functionality.  Do you know if there's a way to perhaps sort the table by a specific column, then outputting the top value of that column?

Comment: you could use `sort`, but what you suggest would be eauivalent to do `df[df$DEPTH == max(df$DEPTH),]`